# Convert location at seconds to DMS/Decimal

Tags: convert, latitude-longitude, degrees-minutes-seconds

I have latitude/longitude represented as amount of seconds:

45'11"35 = 45*60*60 + 11*60 + 35 = 9720695

How can I convert back from something like 9720695 to DMS/Decimal?

Comment: I am not sure why you converted it that way. I go straight from dms to dd with d+m*60+s*3600 ... so the opposite of your seconds conversion. What use would you get from the seconds calculation?

Comment: Sometimes the data comes in this format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using Excel; you will get B1=45, C1=11, D1=35 with formula below.

```
A1: 162695
B1: =FLOOR(A1/3600, 1)             # D
C1: =FLOOR((A1/3600 - B1)*60, 1)   # M
D1: =A1-B1*3600-C1*60              # S
E1: =A1/3600                       # Decimal
```

Sorry I did not notice you were QGIS user. The above excel formula is basically applicable to Field calculator. One pitfall is floor() for negative number so *x* is put in abs(). If your data isn't in west (e.g. -45'11"35 for 45'11"35W) or south this may be overkill.

```
x: 162695
D: floor(abs("x")/3600) 
M: floor((abs("x")/3600 - floor(abs("x")/3600))*60)
S: abs("x")-floor(abs("x")/3600)*3600-(floor((abs("x")/3600-floor(abs("x")/3600))*60))*60
```